# http-equiv - what's equiv stand for?

Tags: html

Everyone knows what *http* stands for `Hyper Text Transport Protocol` for the *HTML* (`Hyper Text Markup Language`). What the heck does `equiv` stand for: equivalent? What does it mean. I know it can be used to specify refresh values and charset/encoding but that's no closer to understanding what it means.

Comment: You should google it ...http://cyberprodigy.blogspot.hk/2009/08/what-does-http-equiv-stands-for.html

Comment: good question, actually everyone tries to just copy/paste it, whilst those really interested in the concept are asking the deep questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

equiv does stand for equivalent. It's equivalent to the HTTP response header. For example, these two are the same

```
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The HTTP header should be used over the `http-equiv` meta tag though.

http://cyberprodigy.blogspot.com/2009/08/what-does-http-equiv-stands-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, equivalent. As in, it has an effect equivalent to specifying the given HTTP header.